# Delphi 10.2 TNetHTTPClient timeouts before its time

Tags: java, delphi, servlets, timeout, session-timeout

I set the ConnectionTimeout to 120000 (2 minutes) and the ResponseTimeout to 60000000 (1000 minutes).

The server is a servlet written in Java and the session timeout there is 30 minutes.

Despite the above, after 30 seconds, the connection is terminated and the response is nil as if something broke it in the middle of the work.

How can I know if it's a client side or a server side? Am I missing something with the responsetimeout I set?

Thanks

Comment: From the same computer, can you try a HTTP request using a different client (such as curl, web browser, Indy ...) to see if they can establish a connection?

Comment: Is some error visible in the Servlet Container log?

Comment: I asked my server admin to check the logs. I don't have direct access to the server to check that. It seems to happen mostly after a server/tomcat restart or war deployment, after that everything is ok. As if it takes time to "fuel" things up.

Comment: Your code should be ready for situations such as redeployment. Depending on the network (proxy / firewall), connection errors may occur quicker than your configured timeout.

Comment: I now handle it in my code but I want to understand the cause, in order to fix it. The handling is for unknown exceptions, the known ones I want to fix :-)

Comment: To have a better (more meaningful) error message, I would write a test client using Indy, or some other HTTP client, or use curl.